# SQL query for TotalPrice by multiplying UnitPrice and Quantity which are inside a XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to query a SQL Server database table, and I do not have control over how poorly this database was designed. I want the total actual daily money (dates are stored in UTC), for the last X days up to today, from data that looks like this:

The SQL Server table contains rows like this:

```
Customer   Customer1
CreateDate 2023-09-11 8:00 am
Items      (column contains XML)
             <ArrayOfItems>
               <Item>
                 <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                 <UnitPrice>3.00</UnitPrice>
               </Item>
             </ArrayOfItems>

Customer   Customer2
CreateDate 2023-09-11 10:00 am
Items      (column contains XML)
             <ArrayOfItems>
               <Item>
                 <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                 <UnitPrice>5.50</UnitPrice>
               </Item>
               <Item>
                 <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                 <UnitPrice>4.00</UnitPrice>
               </Item>
             </ArrayOfItems>

Customer   Customer3
CreateDate 2023-09-12 4:00 pm
Items      (column contains XML)
             <ArrayOfItems>
               <Item>
                 <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                 <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice>
               </Item>
               <Item>
                 <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                 <UnitPrice>3.50</UnitPrice>
               </Item>
             </ArrayOfItems>
```

I want the results to be a total quantity and price, totaled up for each day. For example, I want the output to be:

```
DateCreated   TotalQuantity    TotalPrice
-----------------------------------------
2023-09-11         10             36.50
2023-09-12          5             20.50
```

Obviously this would be much better if the total quantity and `UnitPrice` were calculated at data input time and put into columns of their own, so that I could do a simple query with a sum. Alas, it wasn't designed that way, and I'm stuck with what I've got.

Here's what I've got working so far (note: in this query, I'm putting in an age of "2" in the DateADD section which gets the last two day's worth of data. I could change that to be any number of days in the past, for example, I could get the last 30 days by putting "30" in there, or I could use some other date algorithm. The date isn't what I need help with, it's the TotalPrice that I need help with):

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(date, CreateDate) AS DateCreated,
    SUM (Items.value('sum(/ArrayOfItems/Item/Quantity)', 'int') ) AS TotalQuantity
FROM
    Invoices
WHERE
    DATEADD(day, 2, CreateDate) > GetUtcDate()
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(date, CreateDate)
```

That SQL query above gets me only part way there. It gets the first two columns, but not the last one. I don't know how to have it multiply each item's `Quantity` times `UnitPrice` and then sum all of those up for each day. It's got to do it line-by-line, because each `UnitPrice` will be different. I have this so far, which gets me the quantity, but not the total price for the day. How do I get that?

I've tried searching, but none of the search results are giving me this exact scenario. I'm sure someone must have asked this question before but I can't find it, at least, not this exact scenario. I'm not seeing anything telling me how to iterate the lines for each day like that.

```
DateCreated   TotalQuantity 
---------------------------
2023-09-11         10       
2023-09-12          5
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - I'm sorry, I don't know how to do those things. I thought I had already given the minimum information in the descripton. :(

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XQuery methods `.nodes()` and `.value()` to shred the XML.

Data after the CTE is coming in rectangular/relational format. The rest is basic grouping and SUM() on required columns.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, CreateDate DATE, Items XML);
INSERT @tbl (CreateDate, Items) VALUES
('2023-09-11', N'<ArrayOfItems>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>3.00</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
</ArrayOfItems>'),
('2023-09-11', N'<ArrayOfItems>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>5.50</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>4</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>4.00</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
</ArrayOfItems>'),
('2023-09-12', N'<ArrayOfItems>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>3</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>3.50</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
</ArrayOfItems>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT t.ID, t.CreateDate 
        , c.value('(Quantity/text())[1]', 'INT') AS Quantity
        , c.value('(UnitPrice/text())[1]', 'MONEY') AS UnitPrice
        , c.value('(Quantity/text())[1]', 'INT') * c.value('(UnitPrice/text())[1]', 'MONEY') AS TotalPrice
    FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY Items.nodes('/ArrayOfItems/Item') AS t1(c)
)
-- SELECT * FROM rs  -- uncomment this line to see the data
SELECT CreateDate
    , SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
    , SUM(TotalPrice) AS TotalPrice
FROM rs
GROUP BY rs.CreateDate;
```

**Output**

| CreateDate | TotalQuantity | TotalPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-11 | 10 | 36.50 |
| 2023-09-12 | 5 | 20.50 |

Comment: How is that different from my answer? And why pull out the values a second time for `TotalPrice`?

Comment: We both answered independently from each other in parallel. My answer is intentionally slanted towards simplicity. Shredding is first, feel and see data in a rectangular/relational format. Aggregate as a next step, to produce a desired output.

Comment: Yes but why not just do `Quantity` and `UnitPrice` in the subquery, then aggregate `SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice)` Also `money` is generally a bad idea due to rounding issues, use `decimal` instead.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - Thanks so much for this thoughtful example. Can you explain why the SELECT statements which shred the XML have "[1]" in them? Doesn't that mean it selects only the first entry in an array, thus missing the other items if there's more than one? The numbers in your output look correct, though, so it must somehow work, I just don't understand how.

Comment: @TFabris, XQuery `.value()` method needs a singleton that's why we use "[1]". And no worries, all data is coming out from the shredded XML . You can uncomment `SELECT * FROM rs`, and comment out temporarily aggregation portion below, to see the data in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XQuery's FLWOR expressions to loop through and multiply the values, after converting to the correct type

```sql
Select
    Convert(date,CreateDate) as DateCreated,
    SUM ( Items.value('
      sum(
        for $i in /ArrayOfItems/Item
        return xs:int(($i/Quantity/text())[1]) * xs:decimal(($i/UnitPrice/text())[1])
      )', 'decimal(18,2)') ) AS TotalQuantity
from
    Invoices
where
    CreateDate > DateADD(day, -2, GETUTCDATE())
group by
    Convert(date, CreateDate)
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/5N0Nwiij)

Note the change to the `WHERE` clause to enable indexes to be used.

---

An alternative is to shred the `Item` nodes, and sum them individually

```sql
Select
    Convert(date,CreateDate) as DateCreated,
    SUM (
      x.Item.value('(Quantity/text())[1]','int') *
      x.Item.value('(UnitPrice/text())[1]', 'decimal(18,2)')
    ) AS TotalQuantity
from
    Invoices
CROSS APPLY Items.nodes('/ArrayOfItems/Item') x(Item)
where
    CreateDate > DateADD(day, -2, GETUTCDATE())
group by
    Convert(date, CreateDate)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the examples, the first one looks like the sort of thing I was expecting/hoping to find to begin with. I'll be trying your examples as well as Yitzhak Khabinsky's example and seeing which one works best for me. Both approaches (iterating with FLWOR vs shredding the XML) seem like they should work for my purposes, I'll ping back once I'm able to try them out.

Comment: The FLWOR version seemed to work perfectly for my purposes, and performance-wise, it was very fast. I'm going to try the shredding examples next.

Comment: Your Shredding version also worked and produced similar output, though it seemed slower than the FLWOR version (though I didn't perform multiple tests to be sure of performance).

One interesting side effect is that both the FLWOR and shredding versions result in an output that is seemingly in random order, rather than the date-ordered output that my original code produced (with just the item counts). Don't know why, but, I should  theoretically be able to fix it with a simple "order by" statement, right?

Comment: "order by" statement fixes the problem, but I'm noticing small differences between a run of the FLWOR version and the Shred version when I run it on huge data sets. The differences in the total price outputs are anywhere from a few pennies different to a few dollars different. Not sure which one to trust.

Comment: Probably slight rounding errors. Maybe raise the size of the `decimal` to `decimal(38,19)` or something. You can't rely on ordering unless you specify `ORDER BY`, it could be it parallelized it.

Comment: If some of the unit price values were stored as just a whole number instead of something with two decimal places (for example, the field contained "3" instead of "3.00", could that account for the difference between the two versions? I notice the FLWOR version just says "decimal" but the Shred version says "decimal(18,2)".

Comment: No a pure integer shouldn't matter. `xs:decimal` is an XML type, it technically has unlimited precision. The SQL type `decimal(18, 2)`  might be too low precision for what you are doing.